# Length of a growing substring in matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, for-loop, matrix, max

Given a square matrix find the length of sub string that is growing for example.

```
matrix     |      result       because of
5          |
1 2 3 4 5  |
2 5 2 5 9  |    
7 8 9 0 1 -->       5     -->   1 2 3 4 5
0 0 0 0 0  |
2 3 6 1 2  |
```

I try to compare `a[i][j]` with `a[i][j+1]` and increment the counter but I think my problem is when the program is on the final elements and it does not increment the counter.
Here I have my code:

```
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int i,j,a[n][n];
    for(i = 0;i < n;i++){
        for(j = 0;j <n;j++){
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int max=-9999;
    int counter;
    for(i = 0;i < n;i++){
        counter=0;
        for(j = 0;j <n;j++){
            if(a[i][j]<a[i][j+1]){
                counter++;
            }
            if(counter>max){
                max = counter;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d",max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when `j` is at its maximum (at `n - 1`) the expression `a[i][j+1]` invokes **Undefined Behaviour** because the element `a[i][n]` does not exist (`a[i]` goes from index `0` to `n - 1`).

Comment: What is the significance of it being a square matrix? It can be "flattened" to be a simple 1D array.

Comment: @EugeneSh. this is homework problem and its specifically told that we should use matrix

Comment: Can the longest growing substring span multiple rows? Is it always in the horizontal direction? The problem seems underspecified.

Comment: @ggolen just horizontal and in one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters as the range of indices can not be negative then there is no sense to declare the variable max as having a negative value

```
int max=-9999;
```

It could be initialized at least like

```
int max = 0;
```

In this if statement

```
if(a[i][j]<a[i][j+1]){
```

there can be an access to memory beyond the allocated array when `i` and `j` are equal to `n - 1` due to the expression `a[i][j+1]`.

Also this if statement

```
        if(counter>max){
            max = counter;
        }
```

should be moved outside the inner if statement.

And the variable count should be declared inside the outer loop

You could rewrite the inner for loop the following way

```
    int counter=1;
    for(j = 1;j <n;j++){
        if(a[i][j-1]<a[i][j]){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if(counter>max){
        max = counter;
    }
```

Comment: can you explain why counter and j start from 1 ?

Comment: @itmemilan A sequence that contains one element is a growing sequence with one element.:)